# Algorithm to find very common occurences of substrings in a set of short strings

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I have a list of about 1500 strings from an external database and over time, as a group of business users managed them, they came to have recurring substrings which have semantic value.

I'm building a front-end and would like to present the user with filtering drop down list of those substrings.

For example if I have the input strings:

- US foo
- US bar (Inactive)
- UK bat
- UK baz (Inactive)
- AU womp
- AU rat

I want to get back:

- US
- UK
- AU
- Inactive

My first thoughts are to have a threshold parameter and a list of delimeters.  For the above I might say threshold=.3 and delimiters are space, (, and ).

Then do a string.split on using the delimiters and use a datastructure like a set that that counts repeated items (?)...

I am not trying to have someone do my work for me here - advice on the approach to take from someone who has done this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a good candidate for a Linq approach:

```
var words = from s in listOfStrings
            from word in s.Split(new[] { ' ', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            group word by word;
var dic = words.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Even better, once you've got the groups, do a "where count > threshhold" and an "order by count" and then you've got a query that results in exactly what the user wants.

Comment: i just want to thank again - it worked beautifully and helped me 'think linq'

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be something like you stated. Have a `Dictionary<String, int>` set up to contain your data. Then, it's easy:

```
for each word in string
   if word is in dictionary
      increment dictionary value
   else
      add to dictionary with value of 1
```

Then, simply filter that dictionary based on a threshold, or return the entries sorted by count. You may also choose to have an "ignore list" with common words you don't want to track.

Also, if you want case-insensitivity, construct the dictionary like this: `new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: nice - or i could project the ratio of the itme to its count and then sort by that, giving me items and their descending occurance percentage... this is probably a standard statistical function.. maybe someone will point it out (it reminds me of something i was reading while going over excel functions "for fun" one time)

Comment: You can present it in multiple ways. If you simply want percentage of the string in terms of the total number of tokens, just divide the count by the total number. Some people like to express it as percentage where 100% = the most frequent word, in which case you divide each count by the number of times the most frequent word was found. It depends heavily on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = new List<string>();
input.Add("Foo"); // I'd go for splitting by delimiters as well
input.Add("Bar");
input.Add("Foo");
var results = input.Distinct(); // -> Foo, Bar
```

I'm not quite sure what your threshold is.